# Extend breakable tcolorbox over footer on page break

Tags: margins, page-breaking, tcolorbox

I've defined a `tcolorbox`environment thusly:

```
\newtcolorbox{cajita}[1]{ boxrule=2pt,
  breakable,
  enhanced,
  arc=3mm,
  colback=Orange!15,
  colframe=Orange!70,
  colbacktitle=Orange!35,
  coltitle=black,
  fonttitle={\bfseries},
  attach boxed title to top left={xshift=10pt,yshift*={-\tcboxedtitleheight/2}},
  boxed title style={parbox,boxrule=2pt,boxsep=1.5mm},
  segmentation style={Orange!50,loosely dotted,line width=2pt},
  beforeafter skip=\topskip, title = {#1},
  parbox=false}{}
```

When a page break occcurs, the box stops just under the last line of text and then continues on the next page. However, I'd like the box to continue past the last line of text to the very bottom of the page, past the footer even. Just the box, not the text, of course.

I know this wouldn't make sense aesthetically in most situations, but I promise in this case does. I have an image overlay as the footer so the box would "disappear" behind that image rather than stopping awkwardly just before it.

Can this be done?

EDIT: Image to show what I mean. [image]

EDIT: Minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox{cajita}[1]{ boxrule=2pt,
  breakable,
  enhanced,
  arc=3mm,
  coltitle=black,
  fonttitle={\bfseries},
  attach boxed title to top left={xshift=10pt,yshift*={-\tcboxedtitleheight/2}},
  boxed title style={parbox,boxrule=2pt,boxsep=1.5mm},
  segmentation style={loosely dotted,line width=2pt},
  beforeafter skip=\topskip, title = {#1},
  parbox=false}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{cajita}{mybox}
\lipsum
\end{cajita}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It should be rather easy to extend the box. But the footer is the last thing drawn on a page, so it is always in the foreground. If it should get in the background you need to move its code into the header.

Comment: You could place the `tcolorbox` inside a node of a centered `tikz` graph in an overlay like `\begin{center}\begin{tikzpicture}\node (Here) at (0,0);\end{tikzpicture}\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]\node at (Here){\begin{tcolorbox} ... \end{tkolorbox}}\end{tikzpicture}\end{center}`

Comment: @koleygr which would break completly the breakable option ...

Comment: @UlrikeFischer... you are right... I forgot that... I think I have create some code in an answer for breakable colorbox... but I have not time to find it now... thanks for the comment

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Yes, I want the footer in the foreground. My problem is extending the box past the margins without extending the text content. Thanks both!

Comment: Well make a sensible minimal example.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Ok, I've updated the original post to include it.

Comment: Why do you think that your minimal example needs titlesec and fontspec?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I thought it might be sensible including the whole style sheet... Sorry for my ignorance. Should I remove the color set too?

Comment: The point of an MWE is that we can use it for test. So it should compile for me (which it doesn't currently due to the pictures) and it shouldn't contain irrelevant stuff as this is distracting. Use your little gray cells ...

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Ok, I understand now. Thanks for your patience! I think I fixed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a combination of `enlarge bottom at break by` and `bottomsep at break` or `pad before break`:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox{cajita}[1]{ boxrule=2pt,
  breakable,
  enhanced,
  arc=3mm,
  coltitle=black,
  fonttitle={\bfseries},
  attach boxed title to top left={xshift=10pt,yshift*={-\tcboxedtitleheight/2}},
  boxed title style={parbox,boxrule=2pt,boxsep=1.5mm},
  segmentation style={loosely dotted,line width=2pt},
  beforeafter skip=\topskip, title = {#1},
  enlarge bottom at break by=-3cm,
  %pad before break=3cm,
  bottomsep at break=3cm,
  parbox=false}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{cajita}{mybox}
\lipsum
\end{cajita}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, that solved the problem beautifully!